# SqlCommand.BeginExecuteReader() reports completion before the stored procedure actually finishes

Tags: .net, sql-server

I'm trying to implement a process for monitoring a long running SQL stored procedure. My code calls BeginExecuteReader() on a SqlCommand executing a Stored Procedure. I then poll the IAsyncResult.IsCompleted value in a loop. All the documention online is saying that IsCompleted is only set true when the stored procedure finishes executing.
But I'm finding that it flags true almost immediately, exiting my loop. The thread then blocks when I call EndExecuteReader(), as the stored procedure is still running.

Is there some known issue with IAsyncResult.IsCompleted not working as intended?

It might also be worth mentioning that the stored procedure in question calls a number of child stored procedures. Each of these write messages to the console window (my code extracts these messages via the InfoMessage event). However the SP does not return a result set at the point where IsCompleted is flagging.

```
private static void runEtlLoadStoredProcedure(EtlState etlState, ConcurrentBag<EtlError> errors) {
        using (var executingUc = etlState.Context.CreateNewUserContext()) {     // Create a separate UserContext and SqlConnection so we can concurrently read and write to DB
            executingUc.SqlConn.InfoMessage += (sender, args) => SqlConn_InfoMessage(sender, args, etlState);       // Event handler when messages are generated by the ETL Stored Procedure
            using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(EtlConfig.StagingToLiveStoredProcedure, executingUc.SqlConn) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure }) {
                var asyncResult = command.BeginExecuteReader();
                monitorUntilComplete(etlState, executingUc.SqlConn, command, asyncResult, errors);      // Will periodically check for cancellation, waiting until the SP call has finished
                using(SqlDataReader reader = command.EndExecuteReader(asyncResult)) {                   // Get any result sets returned by the ETL SP

                }
            }
        }
    }

private static void monitorUntilComplete(EtlState etlState, SqlConnection executingConn, SqlCommand sqlCommand, IAsyncResult asyncResult, ConcurrentBag<EtlError> errors) {
        while (!asyncResult.IsCompleted) {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(EtlConfig.StagingToLivePollingIntervalMs);        // Wait for a period of time
            int x = 0;      // Test
            Debug.WriteLine("waiting");
        }
        int y = 1;
    }
```

**Update:**

No change to outcome when using BeginExecuteNonQuery as opposed to reader. Also no change when I remove the SqlConnection.InfoMessage event.
Switching to *ExecuteNonQueryAsync* works; The Task object can be polled until completion. However SqlConnection.InfoMessage events are not firing when using this function, so this has created a new problem.

Does anyone know?

1. What thread do the SqlConnection.InfoMessage events run on? They must run on a worker thread, since they can fire at any point during the stored procedure execution right?
2. Why isn't InfoMessage firing?
3. Are there any other ways of getting access to the SQL Server messages output? Note that the output messages are generated SQL side by calling RAISERROR with severity zero and NOWAIT.

Comment: `ExecuteReader` returns (completes) when a reader is available, and so its asynchronous counterpart would. At that point the procedure has started returning rows (but none will be retrieved until `.Read()` is called). The procedure isn't finished until the last row of the last result set has been processed, but you can't poll for that outside the code that runs the `.Read()` loop. If you want to trace sproc execution a profiler/extended event trace for `RPC:Completed` events would be much more reliable.

Comment: If your stored procedure and all of its children return no result sets at all, I'm honestly not sure *what* the behavior of `BeginExecuteReader` is going to be in terms of when it completes, but I would certainly be loathe to rely on it in any case, as it would trivially break if any result sets are added -- and possibly the process of generating info messages might interfere with it as well.

Comment: Update: Both BeginExecuteReader and BeginExecuteNonQuery are reporting completion immediately. However I'm getting better results using ExecuteNonQueryAsync. But now the SqlConnection.InfoMessage event is not firing. It was working exactly as expected with BeginExecute... so I'm not sure what's different.

Comment: As to your questions: 1. info messages are packets spliced in with the server TDS stream response. There is only one loop to read both results and info/error packets. 2. That sounds like a bug (assuming you are awaiting the call properly somewhere; if you never access the result it's probably that). If you can reproduce it with `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` you can consider [creating an issue](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient). 3. No. Reading the TDS response stream is the only way, and that's what SqlClient does for you in the background, firing the event as it goes.